# Xcode use different Bison

Tags: xcode, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I'm using Bison and Flex in an Xcode project. I didn't want to put the generated files under source control, so I was happy to find that Xcode natively supports Bison/Flex files, generating the parsers on-the-fly in its derived data folder. So far so good.

However, Xcode uses an embedded old Bison version (2.3):

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/yacc
```

which doesn't yet support the `%define api.pure full` directive. Since this bison executable is under the Xcode.app bundle I can't replace it, so I installed the latest version via Brew and added it to my `$PATH` through `~/.bash_profile` (`~/.bashrc` also `source`s my bash profile). So in bash I can say:

```
$ which bison
/usr/local/Cellar/bison/3.0.4/bin//bison
```

However, Xcode still uses it's own version... I suppose the path to the internal bison is hardcoded.

My second approach was to create a custom build rule for Yacc files, and run the correct version of bison from there. This time the problem was that as Xcode ran my custom build rule, it immediately tried to build the resulting C files. The generated C files would however depend on the header file yet to be generated by Flex, because that's where e.g. `yyscan_t` is declared (used by Bison in the generated C file). But on the other hand, Flex-generated C files also include the Bison-generated header, so compiling with Flex first doesn't help...

What I need is to first *only generate* the Flex and Bison headers/sources and then build them along with the rest of the project.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Cant you just edit the Build Rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue by putting the `*.l` and `*.y` files under a `*.parser` folder and adding that folder to the project. Then I removed the `*.l` and `*.y` files added *the folder* to the compiled sources:

[image: compile sources phase]

And then made a Build Rule for `*.parser` like this:

[image: build rule for *.parser]

This enables me to first run yacc and lex and only then will the resulting `*.cpp` files be passed to the compilation step.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out when I encountered the same problem. Still works for XCode 10.1.

One note though. At first I tried to add the folder to my project file. But that doesn't work, because XCode still falls back to the Lex rule, as the .l file is still made part of the project.

It only works when you add the folder to the 'Compile Source' build phase.

It would have been easier if the Xcode devs would just have made the Lex build rule editable. But I don't know how it would handle the dependency where you first want to compile all .y files and only then .l files.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your build target, Build Phases, and click the + on the bar with the search box on it, you can add a New Run Script Phase.  You can then drag that above your current Compile Sources phase.  You can do whatever you want in that script phase, and it will run before compilation starts.

[image: Xcode build target]

Comment: Good plan... but a custom Build Rule (overriding the System Yacc rule), rather than a custom Build Phase, might make more sense, as then it could automatically apply to all yacc files.

Comment: @rickster OP said that didn't work: "My second approach was to create a custom build rule for Yacc files ..."

Comment: Yeah, but I want the generated files to be compiled with the rest of the files just as if they were in the "Compile Sources" phase. But since they are generated on the fly, I don't know any way to add them to the compile phase. Are you aware of any method?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a Zombie, but if I ever come back here again, I will want to see the answer.

Certainly from XCode 12 (probably before) the answer is trivially easy.

(1) Go to build settings
(2a) Press the + for a brand new setting variable.
(2b) Change the NAME to YACC, and it's VALUE to /usr/local/bin/bison (or whatever path you need for brew).

(3a) Press the + for a brand new setting variable.
(3b) Change the NAME to LEX, and it's VALUE to /usr/local/bin/flex (or whatever path you need for brew).

(4+) use the YACC/LEX settings for flags that you want to use.

[image: Build Settings]

Comment: Great news! Thanks!

Comment: So there was a need to use -y so that the filenames are yacc compatible (which is what Xcode expects) - but bison still compiles correctly- it just spits out 'incompatibility' warnings for the extra features.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it with custom build rules, using `bison` installed from `brew` and `flex` that comes with macOS, not the one bundled with Xcode. I'm not sure if my problem was the same as yours, but if you want to take a look my project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/gonzula/splash).